# Low Quality Posts review queue no longer saying "recommend closure"?

Tags: bug, review, user-interface

It seems that there has been a regression in the "close" text in the Low Quality Posts review queue. For example, on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3485646), it can be seen that [a sub-3k user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196603/jk1) is shown to have cast a "vote to close". As far as I am aware, a question cannot be closed by only sub-3k users from the Low Quality Posts queue, unlike how "Recommend Deletion" works. Is the display of "Close" instead of "Recommend Closure" not incorrect?

[image]

Comment: When I go to the question, it only has 1 VtC.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn: that's because the user that selected "close" had less than 3k, and was in effect flagging for closure. The bug is that it says "close", instead of "recommend closure" (which is what I _thought_ it used to say).